# The function "isControlDown()" for an event is CTRL+ALT instead of CTRL in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

So i would like to use CTRL+Z to undo something in my project, So as I have seen online I have done it like this:

```
gridgame.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.Z && event.isControlDown()){
               do stuff...
        } 
});
```

But the problem is when i do this i have to press CTRL+ALT+Z and not only CTRL+Z for the undo.

Comment: change the condition to also check if alt is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is some strange keyboard mapping on the machine you are using. Here are some other options to try:

It's usually preferable to use [`isShortcutDown()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isShortcutDown()) instead of `isControlDown()`, as this will give the expected behavior across multiple platforms (specifically, on a Mac, this will map to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>). This may circumvent your keyboard issues too.

```
gridgame.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.Z && event.isShortcutDown()){
           do stuff...
    } 
});
```

If that doesn't work, try creating a `KeyCombination` and testing via its `match(...)` method. Here you can explicitly instruct it to ignore the state of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key:

```
KeyCombination ctrlZ = new KeyCodeCombinbation(
    KeyCode.Z, 
    KeyCombination.ALT_ANY, 
    KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN
);
// or KeyCombination ctrlZ = KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ignore Alt+Shortcut+Z");
gridgame.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (ctrlZ.match(event)){
           do stuff...
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, I tried this but didn't help my problem but thank you anyway